# Removing NoneTypes from a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, beautifulsoup, nonetype

Before anyone mentions it, I've been all over stackoverflow and Google to find an answer to this and I believe that I may just be doing it wrong.

I'm scrapping an xml document and placing values into variables using BeautifulSoup4. Right now I'm reading the values scrapped into a dictionary and iterating through the dictionary to find the values that I need, however, when I want to print these values into a report with a template I get the following error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Which I've found is the result of having a None value as one of the values in my dictionary. Solution: I've been trying t ofind a way to iterate over my dictionary in python 2.7 to remove or replace the NoneType values but nothing seems to work. some solutions I've found have been the `filter(None, list)` function, the `for k, v in dictionary:
if v in not None: list.append(item)`, `clean = [x for x in list if x != None]`, using lambda, and so on. None of them seem to work which makes me believe I must be doing something wrong. For example, this is how I set up my dictionary:

```
itemDict = []

  for item in soup3.find_all('XMLTag'):
    r = {
        'definition1': item.Starttag.string,
        'definition2': item.Stoptag.string,
        'definition3': item.Filltag.string,
        'definition4': item.Stoptag2.string,

    }
    itemDict.append(r)
```

but moving through it to get rid of or replace the NoneTypes in itemDict has been a pain. The end result I was planning was placing the items in the dictionary into a piece of template code to be printed as a report so for example `"""<Description>"""+item[0]['definition4']+"""</Description>"""`. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

the solution was actually really simple thanks to Martijn Pieters and Steve Jessop.

```
itemDic = []

for newdic in soup3.find_all("XMLTag"):
s = {
    'definition1': newdic.Order.string,
    'definition1': newdic.Code.string,
    'definition1': newdic.Description.string,
    }

for k in s:
    if s[k] is None:
        s[k] = ''

itemDic.append(s)
```

This replaced all NoneTypes that came across from the XML scrape using BeautifulSoup4 with empty strings. Similarly, the code above can also substitute any other value a user would want for a given condition. So for example If I wanted to change every instance of 'fabulous' to 'it was just okay', I would replace 'None' with 'fabulous' and the empty string, '', with 'it was just okay' and viola! Thanks again you guys.

Comment: Print the dictionary before and after your code to remove `None`s (or look at it in the debugger). This will tell you whether it's the None-removing code at fault, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = {
    'definition1': item.Starttag.string,
    'definition2': item.Stoptag.string,
    'definition3': item.Filltag.string,
    'definition4': item.Stoptag2.string,
}

new_r = dict((k, v) for k, v in r.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

But it looks as if you're later going to write `new_r['definition4']`, so removing the keys with `None` entries will just change the exception to a different one. You should make an actual decision what you want to do about the missing data ;-)

Comment: In Python 2.7, use a dict comprehension `{k: v for k, v in r.iteritems() if v is not None}`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I find them unexciting. Apologies to whoever put the work in to implement them.

Comment: Would it be possible to substitute an empty string for the NoneType using the dict comprehension?

Comment: @user2984511: yes, although for that I probably wouldn't create a new dictionary. `for k in r: if r[k] is None: r[k] = ''` to modify the existing dictionary, or change `'definition1': item.Starttag.string` to `'definition1': item.Starttag.string or ''`.

Comment: Got it. The Dict comp from Martijin Pieters is what got it working + the suggestion from Steve Jessop. now I can iterate over a dictionary and have the report printed leaving empty strings in place of None which is exactly what i have been trying to do. The trick was to put the modification into the actual for loop that was reading values into the dictionary. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a dictionary without `None` values in the first place?

```
tags = ('Starttag', 'Stoptag', 'Filltag', 'Stoptag2')

for item in soup3.find_all('XMLTag'):
    r = {}
    for i, tag in enumerate(tags, 1):
        value = getattr(item, tag).string
        if value is not None:
            r['definition' + str(i)] = value
    itemDict.append(r)
```

Comment: a great idea, had not thought of that. But when I tried it I got the good ol' AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string', looking back at me.

Comment: @user2984511: Then you have `None` values *somewhere else* still. This code will *never* add a `None` value to the dictionary.

Comment: @user2984511: How do you get the values *out* of the dictionary. Do you use `dict.get()` by any chance?

Comment: I was planning on using a for loop to iterate over the dictionary to place items in specific spots in a specific set of XML taht will be used to generate a report. so for example I would use the len() function to find out how many certain tags I had, limit the amount of iterations to that maximum amount, and use an aggregator to iterate over each value in the dictionary and place it in a specific spot.